Is the presence of wife necessary for Agnihotra?
Is the upasthithi of wife required to do Agnihotra according to vedas?

Yes it is necessary. Agnihotra should be done in the presence of the couple.So in the absence of wife it's not possible.
See the following verses from the Katyayana Samhita/Smriti:

The rite of placing the Sacred Fire should not be performed by the
twice-born, if they have not even one wife ; all the rites, that are
done [in that state], know, as being not done at all. (5)
Chapter 8



A Homa should never be performed by the 'Ritwik and others in the
absence of the married couple. What is done in their absence becomes
profitless, (i)
Chapter 20



One must not abandon the Vedic Fire on the death of one's wife, but
should perform all the rites therewith as long as one lives. (9)
Having made a golden image of his illustrious wife Sita, the eternal
Rama celebrated many sacrifices along with his brothers. (10)
Chapter 20

Thus, it's clear that without wife it's not possible to perform Vedic rituals and fire rites.
